# Are the odds one in a million?

Tags: probability, recreational-mathematics, puzzle

This is a from a card game call Magic the Gathering
And my question is regarding this video during a tournament match (best of 5). [One in a million](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z8J5AQMZ8V0). You dont need watch the video I will explain the scenario here, but is very exciting.

In this match, player Gabriel Nassif is at 9 life.
And player Patrick Chappin cast 5x copies of [Ignite Memories](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=ignite+memories) targeting Nassif

**Ignite memories:** select a card a random from player hand and deal damage equal to that card convert mana cost or CC for short.

Nassif have 3 cards in hand at that moment.

Ignite Memories CC = 5 
Grapeshot CC = 2 
Rite of Flames CC = 1

*Dont be confused because the 5x Ignite Memories are from Chappin. But Nassif also have one Ignite Memories in hand. In Magic this is call a mirror match because players are using similar strategies*

So if a single Ignite Memories is select from Nassif hand, Nassif will loss 
1x 5 CC + 4 * {1 CC or 2CC} >= 9 life

If select 5x Grapeshot mean 10 life, also lose.

Max damage possible is selecting 5x the Ignite of Memories for 5x 5CC = 25 life loss 
Min damage possible is selecting 5x the Rite of Flames for 5x 1CC = 5 life loss

Again Nassing beign at 9 and 5x copies of Ignite Memories, 
You loss if your life reach 0 or lower.
**What are the odd of survive?.**

At the end Nassif survive and won that game at 1 life but finish lossing the match in the next game.

I only could add 2 link so if anyone want check for the other 2 cards:
gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=GRAPESHOT
gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=rite+of+flame

> I will try to add some context.
>   As far I can go the total number of outcomes is $3^5$ 
>   Now how count wich of those outcomes cause the player to lose can't figure it out.
>
> Also give the motivation of because this is interesting, for a game planning the possible outcomes afect how you make the strategy.

Comment: As I read it, each copy of Ignite Memories reduces life by $1, 2$ or $5$ with $1/3$ chance of each.  You are asking the chancethat after five copies the life reduction is $8$ or less (so Nassing survives).  Is that correct?

Comment: Correct. I try to explain it using the game semantic, but your explaining is much more simple.

Comment: @dustin Im not a mathematic background, I could calculate odd of getting head in a coin toss. In this case the total of sequences is $3^5$. Maybe i over extend the problem as Ross simplify in 2 lines. I read the allow topic and this may be Solving math puzzle. I could post on puzzle.stackexchange but for this problem have a direct math aproach so will be put on hold even faster for be off-topic. I read the guidelines for ask a good question. I feel in the side of context I explain where the problem come from, give great detail on the scenario. Anyway I edit the text, hope that is enought.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If he takes a $5$ hit at any time he is lost, because the other four hits are at least $1$ each.  He can afford up to three $2$ hits.  There are $3^5=243$ sequences of hits.  The number that let him survive are $1$ (all $1$ hits) $+5$ (one $2$ hit and four $1$'s) + $10$ (two $2$ hits and three $1$ hits) + $10$ (three $2$ hits and two $1$'s)$=26$.  So his odds of survival are $\frac {26}{243} \approx 10.7\%$, much better than one in a million.

Comment: Thanks. One last question. I know are 10 possibility for (two 2 hits and three 1 hits) but i did it by hand, can you tell me what is the formula for that. I remember is something like combinatory(5 3).

Comment: Yes, it is the number of combinations choosing three (or two) objects out of five.  It is usually written ${5 \choose 3}=\frac{5!}{(3!)(5-3)!}$